# glew setup in sfml and opengl program doesnt work

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, sfml, glew

I'm trying to use SFML with OpenGL and my setup worked fine.  Then I saw that to use modern OpenGL functions, I need to include `glew` as well.  I tried all day to set this thing up and it doesn't work.

Here's what I did:

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

using namespace std;

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 760), "SFML works!");
sf::Event Event;
sf::Shader defaultShader;

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
};

GLuint VBO, VAO;
int main()
{
    glewInit();
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get these errors:

```
undefined reference to '__glewGenVertexArrays'
undefined reference to '__glewGenBuffers'
undefined reference to '__glewBindVertexArray'
```

and so on for all my functions that I used except `glewInit()`.

I used SFML 2.3. I went to Code::Blocks project settings and

1. linked the `sfml` include folder
2. linked the `sfml` lib
3. declared `sfml_static`

How can I setup `glew`? (`glew` is included in SFML so I though that just with

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

my code should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **statically link the GLEW library**.

Command line:

```
g++ appname -lGLEW -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics
```

Codeblocks:

> Right-click on your projects->Build options->Add->Enter Path to your GLEW lib->OK

Comment: i am on windows..and i included those as well..sfml works fine.its glew that is not working